# Javascript bind() usage

Tags: javascript

I recently saw the following line of code:

```
this.object.on('myEvent', this.myEventFunc.bind(this));
```

I've read the documentation for the bind() function, but I don't understand why it would be used in this context. I read that sometimes the original object to which a function belonged can be lost before the function is called, and that bind() can be used to prevent this. However, if 'object' is lost, how could an event be triggered on it? What's going on here?

(I didn't think I needed to put much code in this question, but if this is not enough, let me know.)

Comment: You should read up on what 'this' means in a language like javascript. A decent answer on your question is a list of books. A good read is bjorn.tipling.com/all-this

Comment: @Pinoniq: Wow, that article is mixing thousands of concepts, resulting in even more example use cases; but does not at all *explain* the mechanics of `this` (which are more trivial than you might think after having read that). I recommend https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: Thanks for the links! I believe that I understand what's going on now.